# keyboard works in the BIOS(except a), but not at the password screen(win 7, 64bit)

Tags: keyboard

The computer is a acer aspire 7720g laptop. When windows want me to input my  password, the only keys working is caps lock, the numpad and the m key(and the m key works like a combined m and enter key). I did spill some water on the keyboard yesterday but the same thing happens with usb keyboards. I disabled the quick boot in the bios, making it go  through every test at bootup, which resulted in continous beeping from the computer. Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I too have 7720g laptop and I've had same experience with spilled liquids.

My advice is to remove the keyboard and let it dry. To do that, you need to remove the battery, unscrew the screws below it and the two screws at the back of the laptop. After that you need to carefully pop the speaker panel. Insert a small screw driver between the speaker panel and bottom cover and carefully disconnect them. After that, you'll be able to remove the keyboard. You should carefully disconnect is from the tabs at the sides and bottom and then very carefully lift it up and move it down. At the lower center of the keyboard there is a cable which connects it to the laptop. Turn the keyboard over and you should be able to disconnect the keyboard at the laptop side.

After that, you should turn the keyboard upside down and let it dry for several days. In the meantime, you can put back the speaker panel and use external keyboard.

Comment: Dry for several days? Seems i might have been a bit hasty letting it dry for 12 hours. Will test it out and report back.

Comment: @christoffer svendsen Well, I spilled ethanol (which is known for its quick drying nature) on my keyboard and it took about a week for it to dry. You see, inside the keyboard there are sandwiched plastic membranes which are supposed to be welded together at all edges, so nothing can get in. Unfortunately, that is not the case and there are small holes though which liquids can get in. Since the membranes are almost inseparable, it is difficult for them to dry because of bad air circulation.